# Run-time error '91' & Outlook.Application = <Object variable or With block variable not set>?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting the "Run-time error '91'" message in my function below? It's happening on this line:

```
Set olMailItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

Also, whenever I'm in debug and I place my cursor over this line, Access gives me this message: "Outlook.Application = < Object variable or With block variable not set >":

```
Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
```

I'm trying to create a button that will open an outlook email message and allow the data entry clerk to edit the message before sending it. I've checked my references and I have Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library checked.

Also, if you have any suggestions on making my code more efficient, please share. I'm fairly new to Access programming.

```
Private Sub EmailButton_Click()
    Dim EmailThis As String

    EmailThis = CreateEmailWithOutlook("myname@company.com", "Testing e-mail Access database", "This is a test")
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "SubmitNewIdeaForm", , "My Name", , "Test", , True
    On Error GoTo CreateEmail_Exit

CreateEmail_Exit:
    Exit Sub

End Sub

Public Function CreateEmailWithOutlook(MessageTo As String, Subject As String, MessageBody As String)

    ' Define app variable and get Outlook using the "New" keyword
    Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem  ' An Outlook Mail item

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    ' Create a new email object
    Set olMailItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    ' Add the To/Subject/Body to the message and display the message
    With olMailItem
        .To = MessageTo
        .Subject = Subject
        .Body = MessageBody
        .Display    ' To show the email message to the user
    End With

    ' Release all object variables
    Set olMailItem = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that, with the Outlook library reference enabled, `olMailItem` is a reserved constant, and I think when you are `Dim olMailItem as Outlook.MailItem` that is not a problem, but trying to set the variable is causing a problem.

Here is the full explanation:

You have declared `olMailItem` as an object variable.

- On the right side of the assignment statement, you are referencing this `Object` prior to setting it's value to an instance of an object. This is basically a recursive error, since you have the object trying to assign itself itself.
- There is another potential error, if `olMailItem` had previously been assigned, this statement would raise another error (probably a `Mismatch` error, since the constant `olMailItem` is an Integer but by using this name inappropriately, you may introduced the mismatch error by passing an `Object` where an `Integer` is expected.

Try changing the name of this variable `olMailItem` to something else, like `mItem`. This code is tested in Excel 2010, Windows 7, I think it should work for Access, too:

```
Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim mItem As Outlook.MailItem  ' An Outlook Mail item

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
' Add the To/Subject/Body to the message and display the message
With mItem
    .To = MessageTo
    .Subject = Subject
    .Body = MessageBody
    .Display    ' To show the email message to the user
End With

' Release all object variables
Set mItem = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
```